# vb.net get/set Properties without logic

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, properties

In many of the articles I have read on the web say that when creating properties in vb.net, they should use the get/set methods and a private/protected member variable in the class.

Like so:

```
Public Class Person
  Private _name as string
  public property Name  as string
    get
      return _name
    end get
    set(byval value as string)
      _name = value
    end set
  end property
end class
```

If there is **no logic** in the get/set of the property, why wouldn't one write that same property like this:

```
Public class Person
  Public Property Name as string
end class
```

Is this because properties were intended to just be accessors into the class from outside and you would store the variable in the class?

Comment: oh, I see. I recognized your answer as "consistancy in your code". I also didn't realize what Auto-Implemented Properties were, until I read the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) about it. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that these guidelines and tutorials were published before VB.NET 4.0 came out. There’s no other reason not to use automatically implemented properties.

Answer (score 1):

While [Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928089/740923) has it spot on, I'll add that being a tutorial, educating the student on how properties work is more important than shortcut implementation.  A more modern tutorial should show the expanded code, then the shortcut.

Ultimately, this depends on the tutorial, whether it's about programming fundamentals and methodology, or about a specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy Tutorials before this was a feature.  The auto-implemented properties notation gives you a terse way of accomplishing consistency of access to your class